# i am facing issue, when i run the flutter application in android emluator

Tags: flutter

D/EGL_emulation(11778): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0d84240: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa0d83350)
D/EGL_emulation(11778): eglCreateContext: 0xa0d843c0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation(11778): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0d843c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa0d833a0)
D/EGL_emulation(11778): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0d84240: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa0d83350)
D/EGL_emulation(11778): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0d843c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa0d833a0)

Comment: welcome to Stack overflow! add code where you are facing this error and also add more details about it which can help to understand  your actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

this is most likely an issue with your flutter version. please show your flutter doctor. restarting the application may also help. if it is a problem with the version, delete the flutter folder and replace it with a new one from the official flutter website. also make sure your emulator is an x86 version or _x86_64